# Annotations on anonymous inner type

Tags: scala, reflection, annotations, scala-reflect

Is it possible to retrieve annotations on anonymous inner type?
I have an example below with which I could drill down to the field in the anonymous inner type via 2 routes and with both, no annotations were found on the field `field`

```
object ReflectionBug {


  @native
  val outer:Int = 5

  val nested = new {
    @native
    val field:Int = 4
  }

  def main(args:Array[String]) = {
    val mirror = scala.reflect.runtime.universe.runtimeMirror(ReflectionBug.getClass.getClassLoader)
    val t = mirror.classSymbol(ReflectionBug.getClass)
    val members = t.toType.members
    val annotatedMembers = members.filter(_.annotations.nonEmpty)
    //Outer is incuded with annotation native
    val subs = members.filter(_.typeSignature.typeSymbol.isType).map(s => s -> s.typeSignature.members)
    //'field' members under nested member has no annotations


    val mirror2 = scala.reflect.runtime.universe.runtimeMirror(ReflectionBug.nested .getClass.getClassLoader)
    val t2 = mirror2.classSymbol(ReflectionBug.nested .getClass)
    val members2 = t2.toType.members
    val annotates2 = members2.filter(_.annotations.nonEmpty)
    //annotates2 does not contain field
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What is the type of `val nested`? It's structural type `AnyRef { val field: Int }`

```
val nested: { val field: Int } = new {
  @native
  val field:Int = 4
}
```

That's the reason why `typeSignature` looses annotation.

You have to find member `nested`, take its right hand side and work with it.

Comment: How do I take its right hand side?
I thought that mirror2 would be doing that as it operates on the result.  But perhaps its just the type again...

Comment: Tried
    val mirror2 = scala.reflect.runtime.universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val t2 = mirror2.reflect(ReflectionBug.nested)
members on that dont show the annotations either

Comment: @JPullar I can't see the way to get to the method symbol without types and as soon as we use type we loose annotation. Right hand side is not in symbol, it's in tree and we don't have trees at runtime (without Sclameta's SemanticDB or Dotty's TASTy). Maybe compile-time reflection (i.e. macros) would help.